# How to aggregate a pandas pivot table across subrows and subcolumns

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, aggregate

I'm using pandas in python to pivot some data and I want to be able to perform 2 types of aggregation across parts of my pivot tables. I'm aware I can use the margins to perform an aggregation across all rows/columns.
But I want to aggregate multiple rows (not all) across a single column or aggregate multiple columns across a single row. How do I best aggregate subrows and subcolumns in pandas?

Example code setup:

```
#Dataset
rows = [
    [1, 'Factory_1', 'crusher', 'electricity_usage', 15],
    [2, 'Factory_1', 'mixer', 'electricity_usage', 11],
    [3, 'Factory_1', 'turner', 'electricity_usage', 12],
    [4, 'Factory_2', 'crusher', 'electricity_usage', 2],
    [5, 'Factory_2', 'mixer', 'electricity_usage', 7],
    [6, 'Factory_2', 'turner', 'electricity_usage', 13],
    [7, 'Factory_1', 'crusher', 'running_hours', 6],
    [8, 'Factory_1', 'mixer', 'running_hours', 5],
    [9, 'Factory_1', 'turner', 'running_hours', 5],
    [10, 'Factory_2', 'crusher', 'running_hours', 1],
    [11, 'Factory_2', 'mixer', 'running_hours', 3],
    [12, 'Factory_2', 'turner', 'running_hours', 6]
]

dataFrame = pds.DataFrame(rows, columns=["id","Location","Type","recorded_type","value"])

#Pivot Table 1: Form multi row aggregation across a single column
ptable_1 = pds.pivot_table(data=dataFrame,index=['Location', 'Type'], columns=["recorded_type"], values=['value'])
print(ptable_1)

#Pivot Table 2: Form multi column aggregation across a single row
ptable_2 = pds.pivot_table(data=dataFrame,index=['recorded_type'], columns=["Location", "Type"], values=['value'])
print(ptable_2)
```

Below I have my attempt at aggregating pivot 1 across multiple rows in a single column. I'm trying to aggregate the sum of all machines recorded_values per location. Can this be done any better?

```
#Form aggregation across multiple rows in a single column

df1 = ptable_1.groupby(level=[0]).sum()
df1['Type'] = ["all", "all"]
#Reset index so machine_location is removed from current index
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
#Set multi-index of location and type
df1.set_index(['Location', 'Type'], inplace=True)
#Concat both dataframes
aggregated_table_1 = pds.concat([ptable_1.reset_index(),df1.reset_index()], ignore_index=True)
#Sort values by location, so appened table values are in the correct position
aggregated_table_1.sort_values('Location', inplace=True)

print(aggregated_table_1)
```

For example, I'm trying to aggregate the electricity usage of all machine-types for a particular factory. So the aggregate is in the Type column with the type 'all'
**The expected output for ptable_1:**

```
+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
|               | Location  |  Type   |       value       |     value     |
+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
| recorded_type |           |         | electricity_usage | running_hours |
|               | Factory_1 | crusher | 15                | 6             |
|               | Factory_1 | mixer   | 11                | 5             |
|               | Factory_1 | turner  | 12                | 5             |
|               | Factory_1 | all     | 38                | 16            |
|               | Factory_2 | crusher | 2                 | 1             |
|               | Factory_2 | mixer   | 7                 | 3             |
|               | Factory_2 | turner  | 13                | 6             |
|               | Factory_2 | all     | 22                | 10            |
+---------------+-----------+---------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Secondly, I'm not sure how to aggregate across subcolums as below to make a sum of all columns per type for ptable_2. The aggregate is a new column with Type as 'all'

**The expected output for ptable_2:**

```
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|     Location      | Factory_1 | Factory_1 | Factory_1 | Factory_1 | Factory_2 | Factory_2 | Factory_2 | Factory_2 |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Type              | crusher   | mixer     | turner    | all       | crusher   | mixer     | turner    | all       |
| recorded_type     |           |           |           |           |           |           |           |           |
| electricity_usage | 15        | 11        | 12        | 38        | 2         | 7         | 13        | 22        |
| running_hours     | 6         | 5         | 5         | 16        | 1         | 3         | 6         | 10        |
+-------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

**Edit 1**
Here is my output straight out of python applying Serge de Gosson de Varennes approach of melt() using default params. I lose track of the recorded_type for each row, which is replaced by a NaN column. Should I be trying to aggregate from this to form my expected output?

```
Df_ex1 = dfex1.melt() # Expected output 1
      NaN      recorded_type  value
0   value  electricity_usage     15
1   value  electricity_usage     11
2   value  electricity_usage     12
3   value  electricity_usage      2
4   value  electricity_usage      7
5   value  electricity_usage     13
6   value      running_hours      6
7   value      running_hours      5
8   value      running_hours      5
9   value      running_hours      1
10  value      running_hours      3
11  value      running_hours      6


Df_exp2 = dfex2.melt() # Expected output 2
      NaN   Location     Type  value
0   value  Factory_1  crusher     15
1   value  Factory_1  crusher      6
2   value  Factory_1    mixer     11
3   value  Factory_1    mixer      5
4   value  Factory_1   turner     12
5   value  Factory_1   turner      5
6   value  Factory_2  crusher      2
7   value  Factory_2  crusher      1
8   value  Factory_2    mixer      7
9   value  Factory_2    mixer      3
10  value  Factory_2   turner     13
11  value  Factory_2   turner      6
```

Comment: Can you please share your expected output for both cases?

Comment: @MayankPorwal hopefully this works for you. I've tried to follow the pandas table styling when printing to console

Comment: For your expected output 2, you simply need to melt the dataframe. You were almost there: ```df = pds.DataFrame(ptable_2)``` and ```df.melt```. Same thing for Expected output 1.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right: you need to melt your dataframe:

```
import pandas as pds
rows = [
    [1, 'Factory_1', 'crusher', 'electricity_usage', 15],
    [2, 'Factory_1', 'mixer', 'electricity_usage', 11],
    [3, 'Factory_1', 'turner', 'electricity_usage', 12],
    [4, 'Factory_2', 'crusher', 'electricity_usage', 2],
    [5, 'Factory_2', 'mixer', 'electricity_usage', 7],
    [6, 'Factory_2', 'turner', 'electricity_usage', 13],
    [7, 'Factory_1', 'crusher', 'running_hours', 6],
    [8, 'Factory_1', 'mixer', 'running_hours', 5],
    [9, 'Factory_1', 'turner', 'running_hours', 5],
    [10, 'Factory_2', 'crusher', 'running_hours', 1],
    [11, 'Factory_2', 'mixer', 'running_hours', 3],
    [12, 'Factory_2', 'turner', 'running_hours', 6]
]

dataFrame = pds.DataFrame(rows, columns=["id","Location","Type","recorded_type","value"])


ptable_1 = pds.pivot_table(data=dataFrame,index=['Location', 'Type'], columns=["recorded_type"], values=['value'])


ptable_2 = pds.pivot_table(data=dataFrame,index=['recorded_type'], columns=["Location", "Type"], values=['value'])
df = pds.DataFrame(ptable_1)

dfex1 = pds.DataFrame(ptable_1)
dfex2 = pds.DataFrame(ptable_2)
```

gives you

```
Df_ex1 = dfex1.melt # Expected output 1
Df_exp2 = dfex2.melt # Expected output 2
```

[image]

Comment: I applied the melt method() using the default params with no luck. There was no total aggregate. Please see my edit above for my output.